# Android first row not selected using setSelection(0) method

Tags: android, android-listview

after multiple try's, i'm using "mListView.setSelection(0);" to select the first row in my ListView when the list appears. But dunno why its not working. So how can I let the first row always clicked? Because in my application i have a listview on left side and a webview on right side. So i need that when my app launchs, the first row always selected so the webview loads the details of the first element per default. The data of the listView are loaded using a cursor Adapter that communicates with an SQLite Database.

This is a part of my code : 
[code](http://paste.org/56430)

Comment: Do you call setSelection after having populated the ListView with your adapter?
Did you call setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) ?

Comment: yes and i added mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); Dunno why the first item still not selected by default.

Comment: [MY CODE](http://paste.org/56430)

Comment: Does the first row get selected with your code? (But data not loaded?)

Comment: No, the first row isn't selected. What i need is to let it selected by default like if someone clicked on it

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up an OnGlobalLayoutListener to your ViewTreeObserver, which sets the selection as soon as the layout is set. (Remember to remove the listener as soon as it's called the first time to avoid repeated calls.)

Check the android sources whether `setSelection(int)` handles unpopulated lists right.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [smoothScrollToPosition(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29) it should work for you.

```
mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

Comment: Sorry but this method won't resolve my problem, what i need is to highlight the row (ex:blue color), not to scroll to the item position

Comment: My class extends Fragment Activity, not ListActivity, and this solution overrides getview() method. So how can i use it in my case?

Comment: aren't you using Custom Adapter?

Comment: I'm using simpleCursor Adapter, you can check my code in the link above